# Fast Fourier to detect piano frequency in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, fft, bandpass-filter

I have a basic knowledge of the fast Fourier and that it transforms the time domain into frequency domain to get all the frequency samples found in a signal or recorded sound ...

i want to create an application that detects all the frequencies in a recorded piano piece and match them with originally detected piano notes and if it catches a match will write the piano sheet based on this concept ... i have this code but i am not sure whether it doesn't work fine ...

The C middle note has originally on a grand piano Frequency of 261.7  but when i use it the output changes over the amplitude of the voice (Ex: 261/262/270 ...etc )

```
   [x,Fs]= readaudio('c4,wav');
   xdft = fft(readaudio(c4.wav);
   [~,index] = sort(abs(xdft() , 'descend'));
   (index(1)*Fs)/length(x) - (fs/length(x));
```

Also i have tried to implement such code visiting many questions and forums but i don't know how to apply it to my idea in general.(here is the code )

```
    [y,Fs] =audioread('49.wav');
    fcuts = [430  438  442  450];             % Frequency Vector (Hz)
    mags =   [0 1 0];        % Magnitude (Defines Passbands & Stopbands)
    devs = [0.05  0.01  0.05];                    % Allowable Deviations
    [n,Wn,beta,ftype] = kaiserord(fcuts,mags,devs,Fs);
    n = n + rem(n,2);
    hh = fir1(n,Wn,ftype,kaiser(n+1,beta),'scale');
    figure(1)
    freqz(hh, 1, 2^14, Fs)
    set(subplot(2,1,1), 'XLim', [0 500])% Set Frequency Axis To Show0-500             Hz
    set(subplot(2,1,2), 'XLim', [0 500])% Set frequency Axis To Show 0-500 Hz
    y_filtered = fftfilt(hh, y);
```

But basically i don't understand it and how to change the Frequency to catch ... but my vision to what i will do is to pass all the frequencies i got from the recorded file to all the keys filters and using if conditions if a match then will write the symbol of the key to the sheet.

please if someone can explain the code and the process to me as i never used matlab before and kind of weak in its commands

Comment: First you need to understand the difference between frequency and pitch.

Comment: is that related to the first code or the second ? please specify the path i need to head over :) because i generally have troubles with matloab programming as well :D

Comment: Nothing to do with Matlab - you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what frequency and pitch are.

Comment: you'r pretty much right ... but my basic understanding of frequency is the number of oscillations in second per hit of the string... The pitch is the difference between the same note frequency and the same note in a higher octave (noting C4 is 261.7 .. c5 will be the double approximately .. .Please correct me if i am wrong and tell me your point of this difference ?

Comment: It's quite a bit more complicated than that - firstly a piano typically has one, two or three strings per note (more strings on the higher notes). Secondly,  each note is actually a complex sound, consisting of a fundamental and multiple harmonics. Thirdly, the pitch that you hear is not necessarily the same as the fundamental frequency, Read up a bit more on pitch perpection and pitch detection algorithms before you try to implement any code.

Comment: I know that the piano has many strings differs on the higher notes but in general when recording from a digital piano or even an acoustic one should result in a combined standard frequency ...that's according to the table of frequencies here in this [link](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-notenames.htm)  which i can use as a sound feature to detect the signal at least ... second thing i know that harmonics are useful in the differentiation between instruments ... for example an A note of 440HZ will differ from piano to guitar.and sure i will keep on reading but is this idea impossible ?

Comment: i am telling you that not to correct you... i am gaining profit from your clear knowledge while talking and correcting my information :)

Comment: No, it's not impossible, but you just need to know that the thing you are trying to measure is *pitch*, and if you want to do it properly then you need to use a *pitch detection algorithm*. Many people mistakenly think that they can just use an FFT and pick out the largest peak and use that to identify the pitch. This generally does not work very well. Look at algorithms such as Harmonic Product Spectrum instead.

Comment: BTW, there are many questions with good answers on this topic right here on StackOverflow - you can probably learn a lot from reading some of these. Search for "pitch" and "pitch detection", and maybe even "guitar tuner" (that seems to be one of the most popular projects).

Comment: Thanks a lot you opened my mind to a whole new path , that's a new breakthrough ... but generally what is the difference between the frequency got by the FFT and the pitch ?? though i found a lot of explanations on the forms you told me about ... ( i mean when do i use the FFT frequency ?)

Comment: An FFT typically just decomposes a complex signal into sinusoids. It's a very useful tool, with many applications, but it's not particularly useful for pitch detection with complex time-varying signals such as music or speech. Note that pitch is a *percept*, i.e. something that you *perceive*, unlike *frequency*, which is a physical, measurable quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pitch is not the same as spectral frequency (as returned by a bare FFT magnitude).  Repeated/periodic ("pitched") waveforms do not have to look anything like a sine wave.

It's possible for all the frequencies returned by an FFT to be completely different from the perceived pitch (see "psychoacoustics" and "missing fundamental").  Most likely all higher harmonics, but possibly some inharmonic overtones as well.  This is especially true for stringed instruments with "big" strings (piano and bass guitar, etc.)

So the problem isn't with your code, but with the fact that you are not using a pitch detection/estimation algorithm, but instead a spectral frequency peak detector.